# didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath is nil

Tags: swift, tableview, nsindexpath

I have a TableViewController which implements the TableViewDelegate methods:

```
public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ParticipantesSearchTableViewCell
    cell.viewModel?.active = true
}

public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ParticipantesSearchTableViewCell
    cell.selectedStateImageView.hidden = true
    cell.viewModel?.active = false
}
```

Please note that I never remove nor set my tableView.editing to true. Also, my `numberOfRowsInSection` method never changes.

If I set my tableView to `tableView.allowsSingleSelection = true` I can select and deselect cells just fine and the above methods fire as aspected. However, when I scroll on my tableView and select a new cell the method didDeselectRowAtIndexPath crashes on `let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ParticipantesSearchTableViewCell`

At this point I debugged `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` and it returns nil.

Any idea what I'm implementing wrong here or if this is a bug? Because I try to use the same table with `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true` and I can select, deselect, and scroll just fine.

Comment: Verify that `indexPath` (not `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`) in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`  is non-nil.  It's also possible the forced downcast to `ParticipantesSearchTableViewCell` is causing the crash.

Comment: The thing is that the cell may not be visible and cells are reused. So it may be nil. Clearly, you should change the datasource, and in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` hide/unhide the imageView, or just override also the `ParticipantesSearchTableViewCell` select method to show/hide the image.

Comment: Try printing indexPath. Maybe the table is nil. IndexPath is not an optional; it cannot be nil

Comment: This confusion had a lot to do with my understanding of how selection in a tableview worked. I followed @Larme advice and change my viewModel layer. Thanks a lot to everyone who helped