# Why will didDeselectItemAt of UICollectionView throw an error of unexpected found nil and crash the app Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have used a collection view to display a collection of images. It is working, but when I make use of the function `didDeselectItemAt` it will crash if I click certain images.

**Error that occurs:**
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

### Code setup:

**numberOfItemsInSection:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}
```

**cellForItemAt:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "ImageCell"
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

        let imageUrls = collection?.imageUrls

        // Configure the cell
        // Reset alpha of first item in collection
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0

            if videoUrl != nil {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                cell.imageView.alpha = 0.5
            }
        }
        cell.imageView.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: (imageUrls?[indexPath.row])!)!)

        return cell
    }
```

**didDeselectItemAt:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            cell.imageView.alpha = 0.6
        })
    }
```

**didSelectItemAt:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("You've tapped me. NICE!! \(indexPath.row)")

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView.alpha = 1

        let url = self.collection?.imageUrls?[indexPath.row]
        self.selectedImageUrl = url

        Alamofire.request(url!).responseImage(completionHandler: {
            (response) in
            if response.result.value != nil {
                self.selectedImage.image = response.result.value
            }
        })

    }
```

Above code is working, but will throw an error if I click certain images. The first cell of every collection view has a alpha of 100% - 1.0 and all other ones has an alpha of 0.6. What I noticed is that - except the first cell of the collection view - every 7th cell has also an alpha of 100% and if the collection view contains a videoUrl it will have a red background and an alpha of 50%..

Is this because of the reusable cells like the UITableViewController, where you use `dequeueReusableCell` and should you use that function too inside the `didDeselectItemAt` or is something else not correctly implemented?

So only the first cell in a collection view should have an alpha of 100, all other 60%. If the object has a videoUrl, the first element will have an alpha of 50% with a red background.

If there are any questions left, please let me know. Thanks in advance and have a great evening!

### UPDATE:

*The following print line will output below code when I click the first image of the collection view and after that the second one. This doesn't crash the app and it will still work*

```
print("OUTPUT \(String(describing: collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)))")
```

Above code snippet I've placed in both `didSelectItemAt` and `didDeselectItemAt`:

**didSelectItemAt output:**

```
OUTPUT Optional(<CollectionViewApp.ImageCollectionViewCell: 0x7ff61679c1a0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (150 0; 150 100); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6080000347c0>>)
```

**didDeselectItemAt output:**

OUTPUT Optional(>)

When I click the first or second image and then the last image in the collection view, the error will occur and will crash my app. The touch on the first image will give me the output:

`OUTPUT Optional(<CollectionViewApp.ImageCollectionViewCell: 0x7fc3cb038540; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (150 0; 150 100); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x610000225980>>)`

The last item - that will let my app crash - will throw the following output: 
`OUTPUT Optional(<CollectionViewApp.ImageCollectionViewCell: 0x7fc3cb03afb0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (300 0; 150 100); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6100002264c0>>)`.

So the crash can be triggered, when you click one of the first images in the collection view and after that one of the last images in the collection view, when the first images are out of canvas. I used a **horizontal** collection view.

Comment: when you look in the console...unwrapping what value throws error?

Comment: every 7th cell videoURL must be == nil

Comment: @Honey The error will highlight this snippet: `let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell`. This is when I click an item. More specific. The array consists of 17 images. When I first click on the second it will work, if I then scroll all the way to the right, and click the 17th image, it will crash and will highlight above code snippet. Hope this will help!

Comment: @Sethmr What do you mean exactly. I created around that if statement another that will check if `indexPath.row == 0` so it should be only applied to the first cell of the collection view I think..

Comment: Do you use any other type of cell in the collectionView besides `ImageCollectionViewCell`?

Comment: I only have one custom cel that is `ImageCollectionViewCell` @marosoaie

Comment: what output does this produce, above the line that crashes? `print(String(describing: collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)))`

Comment: @Caspert Do what marosoaie suggested at both didSelect & didDeselect and tell us if you see any difference

Comment: I updated my question with your suggested information and some extra information. Check the update section of my post. Thank you! @Honey

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that your cell goes off screen when didDeselectItem gets called. Are you trying to deselect the cell programatically anywhere?

Comment: See the comments from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875083/diddeselectrowatindexpath-indexpath-is-nil) and the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972392/how-can-i-fix-crash-when-tap-to-select-row-after-scrolling-the-tableview). Likely it will answer your question

Comment: @marosoaie Yes, when I click between the range of the first and third one, all code works fine. Alpha is set to 100 when selected and deselected will set it back to 0.6. I change the alpha of the cell programmatically with `didSelectItemAt ` and `didDeselectItemAt`. didSelectItemAt will set cell alpha to 100 and didDeselectItemAt will set the last selected item back to alpha 0.6. When I click one of the items in view and then scroll all the way to the right, so the last selected item is not visible in the view and click one of the last items, it will crash...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the crash is happening because when selecting an item, `didDeselectItemAt` can be called for an item that's not visible anymore. 
The `UICollectionView` reuses `UICollectionViewCells`, this means that the `collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)` method will return nil for cells that are not visible. 
To fix this you can use the following code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell else {
        return //the cell is not visible
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        cell.imageView.alpha = 0.6
    })
}
```

Some other suggestions I have for improving your code:

You have a lot of places where you're force unwrapping values.

Consider taking the following approach:

```
guard let url = self.collection?.imageUrls?[indexPath.row] else {
    fatalError("url was nil")
}

self.selectedImageUrl = url

Alamofire.request(url).responseImage(completionHandler: {
    (response) in
    if response.result.value != nil {
        self.selectedImage.image = response.result.value
    }
})
```

By using the guard statement you force the app to crash with an appropriate error message, which will help you when debugging. It's a better practice compared to force unwrapping.

Also, when dequeing cells, you could go for something like this:

```
let cellIdentifier = "ImageCell"
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ImageCollectionViewCell else  {
    fatalError("Wrong cell type")
}
```

This can happen when the cell type is different

Comment: Or you can not crash, and instead log/print an error.