# Why does data returned from coredata become nil after tableview scroll in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Update Note:** This question does not seem to be a duplicate of [How can I fix crash when tap to select row after scrolling the tableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972392) because my issue is specifically about one of my CoreData objects going nil after the table scrolls. But the cell returns data as long as the app doesnt crash due to the nil from the `topic` object.
Basically this part fails: `let estimatedSkills = topic.topicEstimatedSkill` and `let topic = self.topics!.object(at: indexPath.row) as! Topic` even though at first, a debugprint shows that the object is not nil, after scroll, `self.topic` becomes nil.

**Original:**
I hope you can help me because I am a beginner in Swift and apple development in general.

I inherited an ios app that didnt work because the structure of data returned from our server changed. The previous developers cant be reached, so I am trying to make out what to do here. On top of that, in the middle of development, apple forced me to update to swift3 and xcode8 changing the gamerules making everything even more confusing.

So basically I have a tableview that gets data from an object fetched from CoreData. It fills out the cells when initiated, but scrolling makes the data from the object return nil.

The object in question is named `Topic`
and the code fails at:

```
    //TODO - this sometimes gives nil but shouldnt
    if let estimatedSkills = topic.topicEstimatedSkill {
        value = estimatedSkills.doubleValue * Double(cell.starViewContainer.subviews.count);
        debugPrint("success getting estimated skills!" , indexPath, estimatedSkills)
    } else {
        debugPrint("Didnt get estimated skills :(")
    }
```

Then when I return to the original cells, the info in those are gone too.

Here's the tableview function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Identifiers.cells.superTrainer.rawValue, for: indexPath) as! SuperTrainerOverViewCell;
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;

        let topic = self.topics!.object(at: indexPath.row) as! Topic;

        cell.titleLabel.text = topic.topicName;

        var value = 0.0

        //TODO - this sometimes gives nil but shouldnt
        if let estimatedSkills = topic.topicEstimatedSkill {
            value = estimatedSkills.doubleValue * Double(cell.starViewContainer.subviews.count);
            debugPrint("success getting estimated skills!" , indexPath, estimatedSkills)
        } else {
            debugPrint("Didnt get estimated skills :(")
        }

        let wholeStar = Int(floor(value));

        for index in (0..<wholeStar) {
            let imageView = cell.starViewContainer.subviews[index] as! UIImageView;
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon-star-100");
        }

        if(wholeStar < cell.starViewContainer.subviews.count) {
            let decimal = fmod(value, 1);
            var image = UIImage(named: "icon-star-100");

            if(decimal < 0.15) {
               image = UIImage(named: "icon-star-0");

            }else if(decimal >= 0.15 && decimal < 0.4) {
                image = UIImage(named: "icon-star-25");

            }else if(decimal >= 0.4 && decimal < 0.65) {
                image = UIImage(named: "icon-star-50");

            }else if(decimal >= 0.65 && decimal < 0.80) {
                image = UIImage(named: "icon-star-75");
            }

            let imageView = cell.starViewContainer.subviews[wholeStar] as! UIImageView;
            imageView.image = image;
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

The class has a topics property which gets set at:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationItem.title = "SUPERTRAINER".localized;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(rgba: hexColors.gray.rawValue);

    if(Utility.isConnectedToNetwork()) {
        self.getSuperTrainerData(student: self.student!);
    } else {
        self.topics = Topic.getTopics(student: self.student!, context:  NetworkService.sharedInstance.coreDataHandler.context!);
        Utility.showNoConnectionAlertView();
    }

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero);
}


// MARK: Custom Methods
func getSuperTrainerData(student: Student) {
    _ = SwiftSpinner.show("FETCHING_DATA".localized);

    Utility.backgroundThread( background: { () -> Void in
        self.networkService.getSuperTrainerData(student: student) { (complet, returnDics, errorMessage) -> Void in

            if(complet) {
                self.removeSuperTrainerData();
                self.createSuperTrainerData(dics: returnDics!);
            } else {
                Utility.showAlertView(title: "LOGIN_FAILED_TITLE".localized, message: errorMessage);
            }

        }
    }) { () -> Void in
        self.networkService.coreDataHandler.saveContext();
        self.topics = Topic.getTopics(student: self.student!, context:self.networkService.coreDataHandler.context!)!;
        SwiftSpinner.hide();
        self.tableView.reloadData();
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? :) Im too new at swift to figure out all of this quickly right now, so any help is super appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix crash when tap to select row after scrolling the tableview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972392/how-can-i-fix-crash-when-tap-to-select-row-after-scrolling-the-tableview)

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875083/diddeselectrowatindexpath-indexpath-is-nil) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940014/why-will-diddeselectitemat-of-uicollectionview-throw-an-error-of-unexpected-foun) basically its happening because of the nature of the dequeue of the tableView

Comment: Hmm... I dont think it's exactly the same problem, because it's not the cell that becomes nil. It is the object taken from CoreData. It seems to go through a lot of background threading... It just becomes nil as soon as I scroll the tableview... Meaning it's the object itself that fails.

It is this part here:
`let topic = self.topics!.object(at: indexPath.row) as! Topic`

I could pretty much replace IndexPath with a normal Int and it would still fail... :(

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're saying that `topic` is sometimes `nil` when reaching the line `if let estimatedSkills = topic.topicEstimatedSkill`? Asking because it should have crashed before that, at `let topic = self.topics!.object(at: indexPath.row) as! Topic` (and `cell.titleLabel.text = topic.topicName`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out eventually that it was actually a threading(concurrence) problem.

Basically, in the `getSuperTrainerData` function, a bunch of objects were supposed to be created. Given that they returned nill all the time, the ViewController would of course refuse to create the rows.. however, entering the same view twice would have given the app time to store and cache the objects returned from a network call.

I make a call to `Utility.backgroundThread` which is just a wrapper for dispatchQueue. This means that `networkService` was placed inside a background thread. But inside `networkService` there is a call to urlSession. Call to servers create their own background threads, so even though I called my server call throuhg a background thread, it created its own background thread and never returned to the main call.

The solution that I used was to just make a server call, and place the background-object-creation call in the completion handler like so:

```
    self.networkService.getSuperTrainerData(student: student) { (complet, returnDics, errorMessage) -> Void in
        if(complet) {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated.qosClass ).async {
                self.removeSuperTrainerData();
                self.createSuperTrainerData(dics: returnDics!);

                DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
                    print("main queue without completion")
                    self.networkService.coreDataHandler.saveContext();
                    self.topics = Topic.getTopics(student: self.student!, context:self.networkService.coreDataHandler.context!)!;
                    SwiftSpinner.hide();
                    self.tableView.reloadData();
                })
            }

        } else {
            Utility.showAlertView(title: "LOGIN_FAILED_TITLE".localized, message: errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone :)